# Hypergeometric1F1 for large arguments

Tags: gsl

I am trying to use the `gsl` library for calculating 1F1. I have some C code.

The following works and matches Mathematica's results for small real arguments `z` but not large arguments:

```
/* file 1F1.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_sf.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>

double _1F1( double b,
            double c,
            double z)
{
    double Fa = gsl_sf_hyperg_1F1(b, c, z);
    return Fa;
}

int main()
{

  double b = 100000.0;
  double c = 14.0;
  double z = 0.9;
  double result;   
  
  result = _1F1(b, c, z);
  printf("1F1(%.1f, %.1f, %.1f): %e\n", b, c, z, result);

  /* result = 3.2042*10^236 in Mathematica*/

  z = 10*z;

  result = _1F1(b, c, z);
  printf("1F1(%.1f, %.1f, %.1f): %e\n", b, c, z, result);       

  /* result = 9.52444189237289*10^794 in Mathematica*/

  return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
$    gcc -std=c17 -Wall -pedantic 1F1.c -lm -lgsl -lcblas; ./a.out
1F1(100000.0, 14.0, 0.9): 3.204195e+236
1F1(100000.0, 14.0, 9.0): -nan
```

So,how do I get around and evaluate for large `z`, as Mathematica seems to be able to do?
I also tried using the Cephes library version, and got into the same problem.

Why does Mathematica not have this problem? They must be using some other formula for large arguments.

Comment: @njuffa, My thanks, for all these details, I did also post on Computational Science Stack Exchange, and that is now cross-posted here too. The issue appears to be double precision: changing my Cephes-derived code to `long double` gives me a `Inf` answer which is better than `nan`. Perhaps extending the precision further is what is allowing Mathematica to go so much higher.

Comment: @njuffa, I looked at it a few days ago, but was not clear how to call these libraries in C code. I need some more studying to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, I did not tag the question with C. I was not sure what could be done here, thanks for looking into this, @njuffa